# How to make Hasura connect to a specific postgresql schema

Tags: hasura, hasura-docker

By default when i connect Hasura to a postgres database, it connects to the public schema.

Isn't there an option to connect to a different schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasura needs 2 schemas to work: `hdb_catalog` and `hdb_views`.

All other schemas are optional.

You can register objects from any schema if `hasurauser` has access to them.

[image: schemas-in-hasura]

Comment: Thanks. By default, when a database usage grant was given to the graphgl_postgres user, it only have access to public. after granting permission to other shema, they are now visible on the console. Thank you!

Comment: Hasura has access to `public` only because you followed installation instructions, in theory nothing prevents you to not give rights on `public` or even use hasura only as aggregator for remote schemas.